# Not able to fetch mongodb object with a valid field

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm using Mongoengine.
When I do a:

```
>>> Grant.objects().first().client_id
```

The result is as expected.

```
ObjectId('526fd0da82353536892f22ae')
```

But, when I search based on the `client_id`,

`>>> Grant.objects(client_id="526fd0da82353536892f22ae").first()`

I get a InvalidQueryError:

> InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "client_id"
>   Here's what my Grant model looks like:

```
class Grant(db.Document):
    #user_id = db.StringField()
    user = db.ReferenceField(User)
    client_id = db.StringField()
    client = db.ReferenceField(Client)
    code = db.StringField()
    redirect_uri = db.StringField()
    expires = db.DateTimeField()
    scopes = db.ListField()

    #for soft-deleting the grant
    is_deleted = db.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def user_id(self):
        return self.user.id

    @property
    def client_id(self):
        return self.client.id

    def delete(self):
        self.is_deleted = True
```

Can someone go through this code and point out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use it like :

```
Grant.objects(client_id=ObjectId("526fd0da82353536892f22ae")).first()
```

Comment: That did not work either. I'm fetching the Grant object with the 'client' itself - breaking it down to two steps.